# Axios sending HTTPS XHR to port 80 on Chrome

Tags: axios

An API request using Axios from our Vue.js frontend is failing, but only in Chrome.

The network inspector in Chrome / Safari / Firefox shows that Chrome is making the XHR request to port 80, despite the frontend and backend all being HTTPS. Safari and Firefox use 443 as expected.

This wasn’t a problem before. Does anyone know why Axios or Chrome might have started doing this?

**Background**

This problem appears to have started recently, and we have not updated any low-level frontend code in weeks.

The reported error itself is a 504 returned by Cloudflare, which means our origin server is refusing the request, which makes sense given that it’s on port 80 and we’re expecting 443.

We don’t actually specify the port anywhere in our code. I assumed it was inferred from the protocol unless otherwise specified. It looks to me like Axios is doing this itself or via the different adapters in each browser, but I can’t read the compiled JS very well. Chrome and other browsers seem to correctly switch to port 80 when doing local development without TLS.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* the actual problem here.

It turns out that when exporting a `.har` file from Chrome (a saved copy of all the network requests recorded by a web inspector session), it loses or mangles the port data.

Chrome *is* making the HTTPS requests to 443 after all.